# How to create Spotfire datasource with multiple tables

Tags: c#, datasource, tibco, spotfire

I am developing spotfire data source and using [this](http://stn.spotfire.com/stn/Tutorials/HowToCreateSimpleDataSource.aspx), my datasource is going to get data from multiple URL's. For each URL I have to create a table in spotfire. Could you please show me some code to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, note that a single data source *object* can only produce a single table.  That is, you cannot "hardcode" a *list* of URLs in your DataSource class.  However, you can supply a single URL as parameter and require your user of the Spotfire Professional Client to enter the URL when he creates the data table (e.g., by clicking File -> Add Data Table) and have him/her do that multiple times.

The important step in implementing this is to make Spotfire aware of the information supplied as a parameter and make this information serializable (Spotfire Prof. has to store it somewhere in the DXP after all).  You do this by writing a "PromptModel" class, registering together with the associated View (the form that will be displayed to the user to prompt for the URL), and then doing some wiring (registering, implementing the right constructor, etc.).

The example that you linked glances over this stuff unfortunately (you see some comments saying "Not shown...").  However if the Spotfire SDK (TIB_spotfdev*.zip), you'll find a more extensive example called "SpotfireDeveloper.CustomDataSourceExample" that takes care of all these steps.

Comment: Thanks, very helpfull. As I understand I have to write multiple datasource classes, to prevent users every time add Data table manually? Am I right?

Comment: No not really, multiple classes won't help you.  Basically for every data table that will be in your Spotfire DXP file (regardless of whether its a custom data source or something from a built-in data source such a db or a file), the user has to once click "Add Data Table."  There's no way to add multiple Data Tables in one user interaction step AFAIK.

Comment: Can I do this ---> ("Add Data Table.") programmatically?

Comment: Probably yes, but it won't be simple.  The API (https://docs.tibco.com/tibbr_integration?url=pub//spotfire/5.5.0-march-2013/dxp/Index.html&product=1354) has methods to add DataTables etc., and you can work against it with either C# or IronPython.  That being said, it probably won't be fun and at least for the IronPython code, you need a point to hook in your script which basically has to be a button in a text area of your document.

Comment: Could you help me out to figure out where in my code (custom data source) I have to input methods to add DataTables. Piece of code would be very useful.